# Change 'edit account' URL in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

The default edit profile url in drupal 8 looks like http://localhost/user/123/edit where 123 is the user id. Because of this, anyone can see how many users the site has, which I don't want. Is there a way that I can change it to something like http://localhost/user/edit or something without an ID?